# Oracle OpenScript - Link Cannot Be Clicked

Tags: oracle, testing, automated-tests, web-testing, openscript

I am using Oracle OpenScript to test a website.

A particular link cannot be clicked during playback, but it was caught during recording.
In some cases, during playback the link is highlighted and playback stops.
In other cases, instead of following the link, playback is directed back to the previous page (the home page in this case).

I also encountered another similar case where it worked on my colleague's laptop but not on mine, so could be an issue of settings of my browser or OpenScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here was that internet explorer was not zoomed to 100%. This causes some problems with playback using OpenScript on internet explorer.